# deal with Unity 5 UI in augmented reality app

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm trying to make an augmented reality application with vuforia and unity.
whenever it recognize the image target, it must tell a story by showing text , and it should enable the user to press next and back to go on reading the different parts of this story, I'm totally new to unity and don't know how to handle with UI throughout scripting, I need some help on how to accomplish the part of "going forward and backward on showing the story by hitting Next and Back buttons", and all these parts of story should be related to the same image target in the same scene.
I appreciate it if you help me with an example code.

Answer (score 1):

You should create some script that attach on trackable object, maybe something like this.

```
public class DataBook {
    string[] dataBook;
    string idText;
    bool isActive;
}
```

Then you must create another script to set that trackable object is active or not, this link can help you to get that.
https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/unity-how-do-i-get-list-active-trackables

Then after you get the active trackable object, you can set the dialog from the book by create another controller script for button, example

```
 public void Next() {
            DataBook[] books = FindObjectsOfType<DataBook>(); // if the object more than one, it will be more easy if it only the one
            foreach (var book in books)
            {
                if (book.isActive) { 
                    book.idText += 1;
                    textUI.text = book.dataBook[idText]; //textUI assign to object text on canvas

                }
            }

        }
```

you can learn about unity UI Button on this :
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-button

Good luck

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it was very helpful, but I faced some problems which were confusing for me to solve,
1- if I have more than one image target and all attached to the same script "DataBook" where in the code should I fill in the array of data (which will be changeable according to the detected image target)?
2- from the script (findTrackable) how to access and modify the attribute (isActive) which is related to the tracked image target?

thanks in advance